# Can't change PowerShell font and window size on Windows 8.1

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1

My PowerShell window opens with a very small font (and window size). This is a common problem, and I found a bunch of suggestions for how to deal with it, but none of the suggestions seem to work. Specifically, the common suggestion that one should open PowerShell with admin privileges, change the properties, and then close the window, doesn't work. It's still small the next time I open it. The only way I managed to get it to open with the right font and window size, was by opening the application directly. Any invocation via a shortcut doesn't give the right properties.

I'm running Windows 8.1, which seems to be the main difference between my situation and that of the other users who had this problem. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This seems related to this problem (which I still have): http://superuser.com/questions/538607/cannot-change-powershell-default-font-to-lucida-console

Comment: Ah, and I always use Consolas which may explain why I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows 8.1, in *Start*, find PowerShell.

Open file location. Open shortcut Properties (right click menu). Security tab → Edit your permissions to Modify.

Select Font tab (skip errors - nothing is set hence the problem). Select Font (I set Lucida Sans Size 16).

Apply (changes). Security tab Edit permissions remove modify. Apply. All done.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you are adjusting the Properties rather than the 'Defaults'?  Also, I am with Keith; the Consolas fonts give you much large sizes than the Raster, and the Lucida Console give people problems.

[image]

Comment: Ok, after searching for 4h+ this worked for me. Font settings stays. Also this code (from MS Technet forums: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/01109c4e-444a-407a-aceb-82d6f2ef7907/change-default-font-in-powershell-for-windows-81?forum=w8itprogeneral post by
Jeffrey S. Patton) allowed me to add other fonts: `$key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name '0' -Value 'Lucida Console'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name '00' -Value 'Courier New'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name '000' -Value 'Consolas'`

Comment: Yes, it seems to actually be a both immediate and permanent change using *Properties* rather than *Default* (counter intuitive and not what it is for CMD.exe windows).

Comment: A possible explanation for this may or may not be in the excellent article *[Console Improvements in the Windows 10 Technical Preview](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)*, near *"settings are applied in a specific order"* (though the publication date is later in year 2014).

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows 8.1 and the only thing I ever do is start PowerShell via its shortcut then edit the console properties to my liking.  I then launch PowerShell elevated and set the same settings.  Usually that has me pretty well covered on Windows 8.1.  Of course, if you then launch the x86 console for PowerShell you may need to configure it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. [As stated here](https://superuser.com/questions/538607/cannot-change-powershell-default-font-to-lucida-console) I select a non-12pt font, and it works. So I choose 14 pt Consolas. And it works. I'm using Windows 7 and [Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012). Both acts like the same.

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell as Administrator, set the default font properties, and close the PowerShell window.

Then run PowerShell as the normal user, and you should see the same font as you did before.

Comment: Re *"set the default font properties"*: How exactly is this to be done?